# select 2 ancestors on child click toggle/hide

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select two parents elements(a parent sibling, and a grandparent sibling), and have them 'fold' on child click.

I have tried {toggle/hide/show/addClass, etc }.

At first, I tried to select the great-grandparent, but this did not work...; at best would hide everything, and could not toggle back.  The toggle and addClass approach simply did nothing beside prevent default.

The html structure is as follows:

```
great-grandparent <div class='section' id='section-18'>
 grandparent       <div class='docs'>
      parent        <div class='octowrap'>
            *          <a class='octothorpe' href='#section-18'>#</a>
```

edit specific html:
`

```
 <div class='section' id='section-6'>
   <div class='docs'>
    <div class='octowrap'>
      <a class='octothorpe' href='#section-6'>#</a>
    </div>
   <p><strong>image:</strong><br> <IMG SRC="i.jpg" ALT="img" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=90></p>
   </div>
   <div class='code'>

</div>
```

`fold style`

  .fold { display: none; }

below does not work as I would expect, how can I get this code to work?

```
$(function () {
    $('.octothorpe').on({
        click: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var pfold = $(this).closest('.octowrap').siblings('p');
            var cfold = $(this).closest('.docs').siblings('.code');
            $pfold = $(pfold);
            $cfold = $(cfold);
            //$pfold.hide();
            //$cfold.hide();

            if (!$pfold.hasClass("fold") && !$cfold.hasClass("fold")) {
                $cfold.slideUp().addClass('fold');
                $pfold.slideUp().addClass('fold');
                console.log('fold', $('.fold').length);
            } else {

                cfold.slideDown().removeClass('fold');
                pfold.slideDown().removeClass('fold');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

> > edit:
> >     in terms of what I expect the function to do is pfold should select the
> >
> > sibling of octowrap.  cfold should select code sibling of docs.  Then when child ahref is clicked the elements should slideup/down. btw I also tried toggle but no luck!

so whats going on ?

Comment: You need to show us your DOM... We can't see where are `".code"` and `"p"`

Comment: Looks mostly fine to me, other than a few redundancies and inconsistencies that shouldn't affect the outcome. Can you provide a more complete sample of your html? It would also help to expand on *"does not work as I would expect"*.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is right except that the siblings() method throws the jquery objects itself. There is no need to again wrap them as jquery objects. there is also a missing dot before the docs. Here is the corrected code.

```
$('.octothorpe').on({
                      click:function(e){
                          e.preventDefault();
                          var $pfold =$(this).closest('.octowrap').siblings('p');
                          var $cfold =$(this).closest('.docs').siblings('.code');
                          //$pfold.hide();
                          //$cfold.hide();

                          if (!$pfold.hasClass("fold") && !$cfold.hasClass("fold")) {
                              $cfold.slideUp().addClass('fold');
                              $pfold.slideUp().addClass('fold');
                          }
                          else {
                              $cfold.slideDown().removeClass('fold');
                              $pfold.slideDown().removeClass('fold');
                          }    
                      }
                  });
```

Comment: Yeah, I checked the behaviour of your thing; sorry no luck.  It seems to slidUp and slideDown the cfold elements IF the pfold does nothing.  If the pfold element disappears then the cfold is gone as well.  Again, fi pfold does nothing, then cfold will toggle.